# A very basic print out question on Python

Tags: python

```
def show_value(key, dictionary):
    if key in dictionary:
        return dictionary[key]   
    else:
        return key, 'is not a valid key.'


test_dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
```

I run this:

```
print(show_value(5, test_dictionary))
```

The result I expected was: "5 is not a valid key". But it always prints "(5 ,'is not a valid key.')"

I already got it fixed with a little bit of research I just changed it into:

```
return f"{key} is not a valid key."
```

But I still wonder why it wont work because shouldn't it be like this:

```
print(show_value(5, test_dictionary))
```

becomes:

```
print(key, 'is not a valid key.')
```

which would lead to: "5 is not a valid key."

When I just try this:

```
print(key, 'is not a valid key.')
```

it actually works.

I hope someone can help me with this very basic question.

Comment: If the key is not in the dictionary you return a tuple. That's probably not what you intended

Comment: It's not Python itself that turns `key, 'is not a valid key'` in to a single string; that's something `print` does with its positional arguments before actually printing anything.

Comment: [‘very basic question’ is an awful title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615)

Answer (score 2):

`print(key, 'is not a valid key')` is a function call that takes two separate arguments. It's `print` itself that combines those arguments into a single string, as if `print` were defined as

```
# Gross simplification for the purposes of this question
def print(*args):
    sys.stdout.write(' '.join(map(str, args)))
```

The *expression* `key, 'is not a valid key'` simply creates a tuple (the parentheses in something like `(key, 'is not a valid key')` are only needed in certain contexts; it's the *comma* that creates the tuple, and the parentheses simply prevent the comma from being interpreted as something else, for example the separator between arguments in a function call).

When `show_value` returns the *tuple*, `print` doesn't treat a single tuple argument as multiple strings to combine; it just turns  the entire tuple into a string according to the definition of `tuple.__str__`. That is, the following do *very* different things:

```
print(key, 'is not a valid key')  # Two arguments
print((key, 'is not a valid key'))  # One argument
```

(The second example also demonstrates when parentheses *are* required to define a tuple.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and I now understand what my mistake was. I didn't know about the one argument or two ... I just didn't had the deeper understanding what is happening underneath

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic concept, so I will try my best to explain it. When you run:

```
return f"{key} is not a valid key."
```

the function `show_value(key, dictionary)` returns a string which looks like this:

> [key] is not a valid key

where `key` is whatever the value of `key` is.

When you say:

```
return key, "is not a valid key."
```

you are returning a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuples). The tuple is like a list and right now it contains two things: `key` and the string `"is not a valid key"`. Basically you're returning two things, so python prints it out as two things: `(key, "is not a valid  key"`.

It's the difference between returning a instruction from a list and returning the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are printing a tuple instead of a string, when you return 2 items instead of one string.

Answer (score 0):

You will find this easier to implement if you use the dictionary's built-in *get()* functionality. That function takes a parameter that gives a value to be returned if the key doesn't exist.

For example:

```
def show_value(key, dictionary):
    return dictionary.get(key, f'{key} is not a valid key')

test_dictionary = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}

for key in range(1, 6):
    print(show_value(key, test_dictionary))
```

**Output:**

```
a
b
c
d
5 is not a valid key
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use :
`return key, 'is not a valid key.'`
you are creating a python tuple, because python to return  multiple return values from a function converts those values into a tuple, so it converts `return key, 'is not a valid key.'` into `return (key, 'is not a valid key.')` This tuple is then the one object given to the `print` function, equivalent to this: `print((key, 'is not a valid key.'))`

Answer (score 0):

When you try to return 2 or more values:

```
return key, 'is not a valid key.'
```

It returns to you one tuple with two (or more) values

But when you try

```
return f"{key} is not a valid key."
```

It returns only one string.